# Pandas groupy strings with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'Item_No':['001', '001', '002','002','002','003','003'], 
        'kitting':['no','yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no','no','no']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to group by 'Item_No'. Change Kitting column to 'yes' for any Item_no that has at least 1 'yes' otherwise 'no'. And a new Column to get % of total. like below...

```
Item_No     Kitting          %kitting 
    001      yes               50%  
    002      yes               33%
    003       no                0%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is replace non `yes` values to `NaN` in helper column in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for first non missing value and for percentage is used `mean` in lambda function with multiple `100`:

```
m = df['kitting'].eq('yes')
df = (df.assign(m = m, a = df['kitting'].where(m))
        .groupby('Item_No', as_index=False)
        .agg(Kitting = ('a','first'),
             perc = ('m', lambda x: x.mean() * 100))
        .fillna('no'))
print (df)
  Item_No Kitting       perc
0     001     yes  50.000000
1     002     yes  33.333333
2     003      no   0.000000
```

Another idea is use [`ordered categoricals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) and aggregate `min` first:

```
s = pd.Categorical(df['kitting'], ordered=True, categories=['yes','no'])
df = (df.assign(m = s == 'yes', a = s)
        .groupby('Item_No', as_index=False)
        .agg(Kitting = ('a','min'),
             perc = ('m', lambda x: x.mean() * 100)))
print (df)
  Item_No Kitting       perc
0     001     yes  50.000000
1     002     yes  33.333333
2     003      no   0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`GroupBy.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with `normalize` set to `True`. Then use [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to extract where level 1 has `'yes'`. If `prec` is 0 then no `yes` is present.

```
out = df.groupby("Item_No")["kitting"].value_counts(normalize=True)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df["Item_No"].unique(), ["yes", "no"]))
out = out.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).loc[:, "yes"].to_frame("prec")
out = (
    out.assign(kitting=np.where(out["prec"].eq(0), "no", "yes"))
    .rename_axis("Item_No")
    .reset_index()
)

print(out)

  Item_No      prec kitting
0     001  0.500000     yes
1     002  0.333333     yes
2     003  0.000000      no
```

Another option (thanks to jezrael)

```
out = (
    df.groupby("Item_No")["kitting"]
    .value_counts(normalize=True)
    .unstack(fill_value=0)["yes"]
    .to_frame("prec")
)
out.assign(kitting=np.where(out["prec"].eq(0), "no", "yes")).reset_index()
   

 Item_No      prec kitting
0     001  0.500000     yes
1     002  0.333333     yes
2     003  0.000000      no
```

Comment: Also is possible use `df.groupby("Item_No")["kitting"].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(fill_value=0)` here

Comment: @jezrael Cool one. Thanks for the suggestion. mind if I add it to the answer?

Comment: sure, come on ;)